# How to highlight today's date on a calender control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I wants to highlight today's date on calender control, I have written like this

```
<asp:Calendar ID="EndDate" runat="server" 
              OnSelectionChanged="EndDate_OnSelectionChanged" BorderColor="#3366CC" 
              Height="186px" Width="220px" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" 
              CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" 
              Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#003399">
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White">
    </TitleStyle>
</asp:Calendar>
```

and in page load   EndDate.TodaysDate = DateTime.Now;  It works properly on Local host. But when running on remote ,shows yesterdays date as highlighted. What will be the problem?

Comment: Is the server's date yesterday or in a different timezone that when you ran the code it was actually yesterday at that moment?

Comment: I don't know how is the server's date settings. I have run it just now. But still highlight the date as '27' . @Karl Anderson

Comment: Do you have control of the server or no?

Comment: You need to contact the administrator of that server and ask them to confirm that the date of the server is wrong, via Control Panel -> Date and Time.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were setting the value with this code:

```
EndDate.TodaysDate = DateTime.Now;
```

It is inappropriate to use `DateTime.Now` in a web application.  It will return you the local time of the *server*, which as you have noticed is not necessarily the local time of the user of your application.

I've previously blogged about this [here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).  The main point is that your code should not be dependant on the time zone setting of the server.  Deploying your application or moving it to a new host should not invalidate data or functionality.

You didn't give exact time zones, but as an example let's say your server is set to US Pacific Time but you are located in India.  When it is October 6th at 10:00 AM your time, it is October 5th at 9:30 PM in California.  Since you are just selecting a date on the calendar, you don't notice the time portion and it appears to be a whole day off.

You need to put a bit of thought into who the user of this application is.  How will you determine their time zone?  There are many different techniques.  The simplest is just to ask them.  You can provide a drop-down list of time zones, and use that to determine what their current day is.

To produce the drop-down list, use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`.  This will give you a list of `TimeZoneInfo` objects.  Show a dropdown where the text is the `.DisplayName` value, and the value is the `.Id`.

Then when you need to set the calendar's date, you can do the following:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(theTimeZoneId);
DateTime today = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi).Date;
EndDate.TodaysDate = today;
```